# Using JAVA intercepting Jsch prompt for entering password in UNIX shell

Tags: java, shell, unix, sudo, su

I am trying to run shell command using jsch using java program.
Command needs sudo access to get executed. Following is my code sample.

```
   String command1="sudo  restart oraserv";  
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session;
    try {
        session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
         session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected");                
            Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");                
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command1);               
            channel.setInputStream(null);               
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);                 
            InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setPty(true);
            channel.connect();
            byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
            while(true){
              while(in.available()>0){
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
              }
              if(channel.isClosed()){
                System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
              }
              try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("DONE");
    } catch (JSchException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now when i run it it stuck at following

```
Connected
[sudo] password for users:
```

After this nothing happens i want to make it run without prompting for password.
Is there any way i can supply it password for execution to get successful.

Answer (score 6):

The JSCH website gives you an [example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html) on this very issue. The idea is to write the password to the `OutputStream` which represents the "write" end of the ssh connection.
The relevant code block:

```
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("sudo -S -p '' "+command);


InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
OutputStream out=channel.getOutputStream();
((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

channel.connect();

out.write((sudo_pass+"\n").getBytes());
out.flush();
```